# Oracle RPD Ago function SQL equivalent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a function in SQL that can help me compute an aggregate for same period last month or same period last year. For example, Today is 14th November and my current revenue month to date is 1000$. I am looking for a function in SQL that can sum up revenue for for the previous month i.e sept but only for the same period of 14 days. Is there a function that can achieve this?? 
The AGO function in OBIEE (RPD) does this with ease, I am looking to do this using SQL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be as simple as

```
SELECT sum(gains)
FROM business_transactions
WHERE billing_date
      BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 month')
      AND current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 month');
```